# изменение размера динамического массива структур в функции

Tags: c, структуры, динамические-массивы, realloc

Добрый день, имеется структура:

```
typedef struct
{
    int elementov;
    int id;
    int *mas;
} vector;
```

и функция:

```
makemore(vector* vec)
{
    vec = realloc(vec, sizeof(vector) * 12);
}
```

Вот `main`:

```
vector *vec;
vec = (vector*)malloc(sizeof(vector)*5);
vec = makemore(vec);
```

При дальнейших манипуляциях с `vec` оказывается, что память не была перевыделена.
Подскажите - в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Во-первых, какой тип возвращаемого значения у функции? И, во-вторых, почему вы решили, что память не перевыделяется?

Comment: И в-третьих, такое использование `realloc()` - стандартная ошибка...

Comment: Вы чего?? За что закрываете-то?

Comment: А многочисленные диагностические сообщения от компилятора, детально объясняющие суть ошибки, вы просто проигнорировали? `makemore(vector* vec)` уже давно не является легальным объявлением функции в С. Интересно заметить, кстати, что на 32-битной платформе при удачном стечении обстоятельств такой ужас мог даже и "работать", благодаря знаменитому эффекту "забыл `return` - "возвращается" результат последенего вызова функции"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При дальнейших попытках обратиться к 5-му и далее элементам vec,  вылазила ошибка "куча повреждена".
 Исправил ошибку, всем спасибо за помощь! Задал функции тип vector* и вернул указатель на vec.

Comment: И ошибку с вызовом `realloc()` исправили?

Comment: @PinkTux ошибка может возникнуть в случае, когда память не будет перевыделена и vec будет ссылаться на неизвестный участок в памяти?

Comment: Не на неизвестный, а в NULL. Плюс при этом вы потеряете старое значение.

Comment: @PinkTux спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 1):

```
makemore(vector* vec)
{
    vec = realloc(vec, sizeof(vector) * 12);
}
```

Странно, как современный компилятор не обругал вас вот тут:

```
vec = makemore(vec);
```

Вы же ничего из `makemore` не возвращаете...

Так что - а как вы, собственно, узнали, что память не была перевыделена?

Comment: Более того, строка `arg = realloc(arg, ...);` -- это на 99.99% баг в коде.

Comment: @0andriy: Неверно. Опять вы делаете слепое карго-культовое применение шаблонного правила, не разобравшись детально в ситуации. Если функция `makemore` задумана, как "тонкая" оболочка над `realloc` (то есть она так же как `realloc` принимает старый указатель и возвращает новый указатель), то то самое правило, которое вы пытаетесь применить, теперь надо применять именно к `makemore`. То есть `p = makemore(p)` будет вашим "99.99% багом в коде", а про `vec = realloc(vec, ...` внутри `makemore` ничего подобного сказать нельзя.

Comment: @ant, неверно трактуете, ну да ладно, переубеждать никого не буду, жаль только,  что люди не против больше говнокода производить, даже под это подводят целые "тонкие" теории.

Comment: @0andriy: А зачем "теории"? Приведите элементарный пример, когда это может привести к проблемам в ситуации, когда `makemore` просто заоболачивает `realloc`?